# Question 'undelete' command is apparently mislabelled

Tags: discussion, design, vote-to-undelete

I clicked 'undelete' on a question I'd previously undeleted, and the question didn't get undeleted. Instead I saw a message saying 'your undelete has been recorded' or similar. I don't see that message anymore.

If (if) it is not intended to perform an undelete, why is it labelled undelete?

Comment: I think you'll find the hover over says: "*vote* to undelete"?

Answer (score 3):

This is done for *brevity* - the full text is available in the tooltip, as @JonClements mentions. *Vote to undelete* would be a bit long, compared to the other links under the post which are just a single word. It might be a little bit confusing the first time, but you'll get used to it.

In a similar way, once you get to 3000 reputation, you'll be able to vote to close questions. However, the link says just 'close', even though there are five close *votes* necessary to actually close a question.

Comment: "This is done for brevity " brevity, concise and exact use of words in writing or speech. Doesn't say inaccurate ;) " It might be a little bit confusing the first time". Not a little confusing. A lot misleading. I would never had clicked it had it not said 'undelete'.

Comment: "the full text is available in the tooltip" Thanks. I''ll be sure to check the tooltip before next using any command here for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from what Glorfindel points out about brevity and consistency, there is another larger conceptual point to be made here: you are mixing together semantics and implementation details.

When deciding whether to click "undelete" (or "close" or whatever), we want you to approach the decision *as if* your single vote was going to be binding, and the status of the item was going to instantly change.

Yes, in point of fact, you are just casting a single vote, and multiple votes are going to be required in order for there to be any action taken. However, you should not vote with this in mind. The links are labeled as they are to help *discourage* you from clicking it for kicks-and-giggles. Your vote is your word. You should stand by it, just as if it had the full power of execution. And eventually it might. Your name will be displayed if/when the post gets eventually undeleted as one of the people responsible.

In fact, sometimes it does—such as when the post already has enough votes from other community members that yours will be the final vote that puts it over the edge. Yes, again, this is generally going to be explicitly demarcated by a vote count next to the link (*e.g.*, "undelete (2)"), but you have to know exactly what the vote thresholds are for each action in order for that to be meaningful to you, which hardly anyone actually remembers.

The voting system is not used to protect against misclicks, but rather to <strike>suppress individual voices</strike> achieve (at least somewhat of a) community consensus.

Comment: "When deciding whether to click "undelete" (or "close" or whatever), we want you to approach the decision as if your single vote was going to be binding" Who ever "we" is needs to think a bit more on that. I didn't make any decision about a vote. I wasn't told there'd be a vote.

Comment: "The voting system is not used to protect against misclicks, but rather to suppress individual voices achieve (at least somewhat of a) community consensus." I won't ask why 'delete' was allowed without a community consensus!

Comment: Are you one of those new people who ignore all elections, because "votes don't make any sense?". If deletion was single voice, the  vote undelete is exact reason why. That's to balance out the opinions. Otherwise you'll get eternal war of edits, where one deletes and other one undeletes :P

Comment: Your comments make very little sense to me, @Chris. It sounds like you didn't understand the answer. The whole point is that you didn't make any decision about a vote. You decided whether or not to click the link, based on the assumption that the action would be immediately triggered. The whole point of my answer is that that is the intended design. Delete is not allowed without a community consensus, either, except when it's your own post.

Comment: "You decided whether or not to click the link, based on the assumption that the action would be immediately triggered. The whole point of my answer is that that is the intended design." Ah, got you. I'd not realised you were pointing out that the interface is designed to deceive. Thanks. "Delete is not allowed without a community consensus, either, except when it's your own post" FAOD, the post on which I clicked undelete was my own post.